# Plotting points on a map based on address text string of location

Tags: qgis, google-maps, gecoding

This may be a naive question, but I'll try anyway.

I am working in QGIS, and I have a shapefile with more than 2000 rows containing information about specific trees in a botanical garden; their location in the garden as well as the age of the tree, and – importantly – where the seed for the tree originated. This last information is however stored as real text ("Honshu, Toyama Prefect, Japan" for instance). I would like to be able to take this entire column of text fields and, through a Google Maps lookup or something like that, convert these in to coordinates, so that I can use this column to plot the origins on a world map.

Does anyone know of a way to accomplish this, the conversion of real text to coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The process is called "geocoding" and you can use the MMQGIS plugin for it. You can find detailed documentation at http://michaelminn.com/linux/mmqgis/

Comment: Could you share some examples of how to use the plugin to look up a text value from an attribute field?

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck? It should be fairly straightforward or at least easy with some trial and error.